# Google Play Music: Download Entire Library through USB (instead of internet)

Tags: google-play-music

I've used Google's Music Manager to upload my entire iTunes library (songs and playlists) to Play Music.

Now I need my library in my phone as well but the Play Music app on my Android phone only lets me download over the internet. I have 15 GB of songs and I was wondering if I can transfer my songs via USB instead.

Will the USB-transferred songs conflict with my Play Music library?

Comment: Seems as though you might be able to test this for yourself with just a single song.

Comment: Do you mean, copy your music library from local storage via USB directly to your phone? Google's Play Music appears to store the songs in it's own database format once downloaded to your device so I imagine there would need to be a process of "importing" if this is going to be possible.

Comment: I just tried copying an mp3 file to my phones "Music" folder, but after 2+ hours Google Play Music has not picked it up.

Comment: I just copied into the Media > Audio folder and Play Music picked it up. You may need to reboot to re-run its media scanning.

Comment: Yes (as @RossC mentions above) the next day (having switched my phone off overnight - Media scan on boot I suspect) my mp3 (copied to the Music folder) has indeed been picked up by Play Music. :) (I used to have the "Rescan Media" app installed, but that seems to have stopped working with KitKat!)